# unable to build core-image-sato with yocto rocko

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm just starting out with yocto. Reading Embedded [Linux Systems with the Yocto Project](http://book.yoctoprojectbook.com/index). Downloaded latest rocko release with git, created a new environment and ran `bitbake core-image-sato`. Got the following errors during build

```
ERROR: binutils-native-2.29-r0 do_install: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: binutils-native-2.29-r0 do_install: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /home/some-user/projects/rpi-yocto-build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-native/2.29-r0/temp/log.do_install.73730)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/some-user/projects/rpi-yocto-build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-native/2.29-r0/temp/log.do_install.73730
...
...
...
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/some-user/projects/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/binutils/binutils_2.29.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 826 tasks of which 431 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

Looked at the `home/some-user/projects/rpi-yocto-build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-native/2.29-r0/temp/log.do_install.73730` log file and found the following in it

```
/home/some-user/projects/rpi-yocto-build/tmp/hosttools/ld: cannot find ../bfd/.libs/libbfd.a: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:1116: recipe for target 'ld-new' failed
make[4]: *** [ld-new] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/some-user/projects/rpi-yocto-build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-native/2.29-r0/git/build.x86_64-linux.x86_64-linux/ld'
Makefile:1760: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/some-user/projects/rpi-yocto-build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-native/2.29-r0/git/build.x86_64-linux.x86_64-linux/ld'
Makefile:1931: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/some-user/projects/rpi-yocto-build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-native/2.29-r0/git/build.x86_64-linux.x86_64-linux/ld'
Makefile:7204: recipe for target 'install-ld' failed
make[1]: *** [install-ld] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs...
```

Is `../bfd/.libs/libbfd.a` something I should have installed on my machine or it is `rocko` that is missing it? Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I gave image-core-sato on an otherwise unmodified poky checkout on the rocko branch a test, and it built successfully. If you could state your MACHINE setting and eventually layer in use besides what comes with poky, I can try to reproduce the failure. Otherwise, have you already tried Ross' suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that that isn't the actual error, but a subsequent one.  Can you do bitbake binutils-native -cclean (to wipe away the partial build) and then bitbake binutils-native, and assuming it breaks again pastebin the *entire* log.do_install.

Also I've not read that book but it might be worth trying with MACHINE=qemux86 from just a clone of Poky, so we can rule out other layers or configuration.